# Question about the notation or idea used in this proof

Tags: calculus

Could someone please explain the idea behind the red arrow. Not sure if I follow. To me it looks like treating an indefinite integral as a definite integral or am I barking up the wrong acyclic connected graph?

[image: image for question]

Thanks

Comment: What is the derivative of $z\mapsto -e^{-\frac{1}{2} \frac{z^2}{\sigma^2}}$?

Comment: _Acyclic connected_ graph. It's not an indefinite integral, but an infinite integral. Treat it like a limit of finite integrals.

Comment: If $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ (and all the integrals exist, of course), then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z) dz = \lim_{z \to \infty} F(z) - \lim_{z \to -\infty} F(z)$.

Comment: So for any definite integral $\int_{a}^b f(z) dz = \lim_{z \to b} F(z) - \lim_{z \to a} F(z)$. Must have missed this but nice to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for a differentiable function $\;f\;$ , we have that

$$\int f'(x)\,e^{f(x)}\,dx= e^{f(x)}+C$$

Since you have an improper integral, you get

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f'(z)\,e^{f(z)}\,dz=\left. e^{f(z)}\right|_{-\infty}^\infty\;,\;\;\text{with}\;\;f(z)=-\frac12\frac{z^2}{\sigma^2}$$

and, in fact, what one *must* do is

$$\left.e^{f(x)}\right|_{-\infty}^\infty=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{f(x)}-\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^{f(x)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the integral in the line above the arrow has limits on it, so it is a definite integral.  The quantity in the large parentheses is the indefinite integral and the superscript/subscript indicate you are to evaluate it at those limits and subtract to get the value of the definite integral.  This is done in the next line, where they make explicit the fact that you need to take the limit as the bounds go to infinity.